# Bold Commerce - Subscriptions - Adding Order Frequency Tag to Shopify Orders

Tags: shopify, subscription

I've installed Bold Subscriptions on my Shopify store and would like the order frequency ( frequency_num ) to come through as a tag every time a new subscription order is generated in Shopify.

Has anyone ever done this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I had to make an App to do that because Yotpo is too crappy to provide that. I am sure Bold provides that as a service. If not, a simple App will do the trick. At least ask them to hack that in if it is not a thing. Simple enough and they have nothing better to do than serve you, their customer.